# Prove that AB = 0 for two matrices if rank(A) < n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

#### Problem

Suppose I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ with $rank(A) < n$.

I need to prove: $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \; \exists B \neq 0 \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times k} : AB = 0$

#### Approach

Since $rank(A) < n$ at least one column of $A$ is linearly dependent, which means we can bring the matrix into the row echelon form and get one zero row/column. That implies that for the dot product of the zero row and some arbitrary column of B, *some* entries in B do not matter, which means we can fill the matrix with zeroes everywhere else and choose these special coefficients such that the matrix multiplication yields the zero matrix $0 \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times k}$

I'm pretty sure my approach is wrong. Also, I can't seem to find out how to prove this in a rigorous mathematical/symbolical way.

Any hints are highly appreciated. I'm new in university and still need to get used to this kind of abstract problem solving thinking.

Comment: All you need is a nonzero vector with $Av=0$. You can then fill $B$ with multiples of $v$ as columns.

Comment: You can row reduce matrices by multiplying them with elementary matrices. These matrices are invertible. This should help to make your argument rigorous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View $A$ as a linear map from $\mathbb{K}^n$ t0 $\mathbb{K}^m$. Then by the [fundamental theorem of linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), we have
$$\text{dim }\mathbb{K}^n = \text{dim null }A + \text{dim range }A.$$
Since $\text{dim }\mathbb{K}^n = n$ and $\text{dim range }A = \text{rank }A$ we get
$$\text{dim null }A = n - \text{rank }A.$$
If $\text{rank }A < n$, then
$$\text{dim null }A \geq 1,$$
which means that $A$ has a nonzero nullspace. If you fill the columns of $B$ with vectors in the null space of $A$ then $AB = 0$.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $B$ has columns $b_1,\dots,b_k$, then 
$$
AB = A \pmatrix{b_1 & \cdots & b_k} = \pmatrix{Ab_1 & \cdots & Ab_k}.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate this? So my product matrix has the columns $Ab_1, \dots, Ab_k$, still I would need to prove that $Ab_i=0 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., k\}$.

Comment: The point is that as long as $Ax = 0$ has a non-zero solution $x$, you can build a matrix $B$ by selecting $b_i$ that satisfy $Ab_i = 0$.